# Validation de traduction / Translation Review ?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

Suite a une question sur le [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/conversation/a-propos-des-valiadtions-de-traduction) pour confirmer une traduction d'entrée en matière j'en suis venu à me demander quelle était la position du site sur une revue de traduction comme cela peut se faire en revue de code sur [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Parfois une question demandant la validation de traduction d'une phrase peut amener a des interprétations différentes en fonction du contexte, il  me semble qu'il serait plus efficace pour l'auteur de demander une revue de sa traduction plutôt que de poser plusieurs questions séparées.

Je ne remet pas en question la page 'How to ask':

> **What about translations?** We are not a translation service, nor do we
>   purport to be experts in languages other than French. Asking about the
>   meaning of a difficult French sentence is fine. So is asking how to
>   express an idea in idiomatic French. But please don't ask us to
>   translate a text to or from another language.

Je parle ici de valider une traduction existante (éventuellement de la corriger) et pas de faire une traduction complète.

Quelle est la position de la communauté sur ce type de questions ?

Des étiquettes synonyme [pour-relecture](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pour-relecture) et [for-review](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/for-review) seraient-elles utiles pour ce cas d'usage ?

---

After a question in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/conversation/a-propos-des-valiadtions-de-traduction) about how to word a greetings I came to ask myself what is the site policy about translation reviews how it can be done on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Sometimes a question asking for a review for translation of a single sentence can lead to different interpretations when there's not enough context, I feel it would be better and more effective for the author to ask for a global review of his/her translation than to ask multiple separate questions.

I don't aim to invalidate 'How to ask' in any way:

> **What about translations?** We are not a translation service, nor do we
>   purport to be experts in languages other than French. Asking about the
>   meaning of a difficult French sentence is fine. So is asking how to
>   express an idea in idiomatic French. But please don't ask us to
>   translate a text to or from another language.

I'm talking here only about review (and eventually alternatives propositions) and not about full translation.

What's the community stake on this kind of questions ?

Would [pour-relecture](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pour-relecture) and [for-review](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/for-review) be useful synonym tags for this use case ?

Comment: I had small text in mind when writing this question, like a short mail. Seems there's few traction, I can't see the votes balance actually but as only one answer against it is present after 87 views. I assume this is not something this community wish.

Comment: I don't think it would be too out of line to divulge that the votes cast thus far are 80% positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stepping away from what we already do on French Language does not only seem unnecessary, to my mind it does not fit in with Stack Exchange primary purpose of building a library of questions and answers on specific topics and avoiding answers based on opinions, rather than facts,

There's no way one could compare code reviewing and translation reviewing. Even when two programmers write in different ways a programme having the same target, there's a must one can't escape: the programme must work. If this prerequisite is fulfilled then one can evaluate other criteria, length, running time,  etc. (I'm not a programmer so I won't expand on the subject of code reviewing).

Reviewing a translation implies evaluating the text produced in the target language. In order to translate a text one needs an excellent knowledge in both languages, source language and target language. Even though quite a lot of translators are bi-lingual, translators usually translate into their native tongue.
Two translators can do different translations that can both be  good because translating is not a scientific activity like coding, it implies  interpreting the source text and  putting it into words in the target language.
To write this text one has  to make choices that are very often seen through the lens of one's own sensibility, it is subjective. Initial choices are made that influence the translation throughout. I doubt the translation of a whole work, even as short as a few pages, would be tackled on Stack Exchange.  But even the translation of one paragraph or one sentence needs to fit in the global contexts of both, source and target languages. So we fall back onto what we already have: how to say such & such in French.

All Stack Exchange language sites aim at building a library of detailed answers to every question about the (X) language. I personally think it is important Stack Exchange language sites keep this format of one question corresponding to one specific topic. This format allows to ask translation questions,  to me [this one](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1010/358) for instance seems to be on topic on French Language.

Even Area 51 **Translating** proposal does not intend to go about translating texts, but discussing the work and art of translators. [Robert Cartaino's* answer](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25830/43945) is very clear about that. I agree with him.

> Our single-language sites do not allow translation requests, and our more technical sites do not allow questions like "Can someone write this program for me?" This is a site for professionals and enthusiast *in* this field *about* this field. Creating a translation service for the general public would not be consistent with the audience targeted by this Q&A.

<sup>*He is Director of Community Development for the Stack Exchange Network</sup>

---

Je ne vois pas de raisons de changer ce qui se fait déjà, à savoir demander comment rendre tel mot ou telle expression en français.

On ne peut pas comparer la validation de code et la validation d'une traduction. Même si deux programmeurs écrivent  de façons différentes un programme dont le but est le même, il me semble qu'il y ait un incontournable non subjectif : le programme doit marcher. Ensuite on peut évaluer sur d'autres critères non subjectifs eux aussi : temps d’exécution, nombre de lignes, etc... (je ne m'étends pas car je ne suis pas programmeur de métier)

« Valider une traduction » revient à valider un texte qui a été soumis au filtre du traducteur qui interprète un texte (activité subjective) qu'il n'a pas écrit pour l'exprimer dans une  langue différente.
Traduire demande une excellente connaissance dans les deux langues même si les traducteurs professionnels ne traduisent en principe que vers leur langue maternelle. Même si de nombreux traducteurs professionnels sont bilingues, il y a toujours une des deux langues qui est « meilleure ».  Une traduction n'est pas une activité scientifique comme le codage mais fait intervenir des choix de départ qui découlent de ressentis subjectifs et non de critères scientifiques.  Deux traducteurs peuvent faire des traductions différentes et néanmoins valables. Le traducteur analyse le texte de départ, il l'interprète, lui donne un sens personnel qui n'est qu'un sens parmi d'autres possibles. À partir de cette interprétation il fait des choix de départ qui sous-tendent toute la traduction, la traduction d'un texte ne peut se faire que dans un contexte global. Même si je me doute que sur Stack Exchange on ne se lancerait pas  dans la traduction d'une œuvre entière, ne fut-elle que de 2 ou 3 pages,  la traduction de seulement un paragraphe ou même une phrase ne peut être jugée que dans les contextes complets des textes de  départ et d'arrivée.

Tous les sites de langues de Stack Exchange ont pour but de « constituer une bibliothèque la plus exhaustive possible de questions concernant [la langue du site] ». Personnellement je pense très important que les sites de langues gardent se format de « site de référence » où une question correspond à un point à traiter. Ce qui bien sûr n'empêche pas de poser des questions de français liées à une traduction. Il y en a quelques unes qui ont tout à fait leur place sur French Language, par exemple celle-ci : [Comment pourrait-on dire en français « at the end of the day » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1010/358).

La proposition  d'Area 51 ** Translating** n'a pas pour but de faire des traductions de texte mais de discuter de l'art et du métier de traducteur. [La réponse de Robert Cartaino](http://ttps://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25830/43945)  (Director of Community Development for the Stack Exchange Network) est explicite à ce sujet, et je suis d'accord avec lui.

Comment: This answer is biased over the whole omission code review is reviewing a work of translating an algorithm (an idea) in a language (literally a programming language) and giving advices on the resulting translation to improve it.  I had in mind short texts and not wholes pages, something less than 6 or 7 sentences.

Comment: @Tensibai Is my first assumption that code **has to work** wrong then? As I said I'm not a programmer, and I can't see what good would be code that doe not work in a programme. For the rest as I said "the translation of one paragraph or one sentence needs to fit in the global contexts of both, source and target languages."

Comment: It has to work, as a translation has to be intelligible. But doing two loops where one would be enough is redundant and can be improved, as well as some redundancy we can find when someone speak a foreign language. This proposition is just to avoid questions lacking context when it could help and sometimes to help providing a better idea to OP than the one he/she is struggling with (I admit it is vaguely hypothetical)

Comment: My point being, coding is also translating an idea into a language, that's less different than you may think at first glance. Most programming language allow to do/express something in multiple manners, some are more idiomatic to a language than an another, the goal of a code review is to give advice on the most idiomatic way to get the same result :)

Comment: Je me rends compte que j'ai oublié de dire que je me faisais un peu l'avocat du diable dans les commentaires ci dessus :) La réponse me paraît tout à fait sensée (et j'ai voté pour). Je pense l'accepter demain ou après demain pour clore le sujet au vu du peu d'engouement qu'il succiscte

Answer (score 1):

Laure's answer seems very reasonable to me, but for the sake of examining both sides fully I'll give some thoughts tending towards the opposite conclusion (with many caveats!).

I think the comparison with Code Review is apt. In my experience programming is half math and half language, and I approach it through the latter lens. The work raises questions that correspond to semantics (which item is most suitable here), syntax (how must I arrange these items), and style (how shall I make this concise yet clear). And judgement is involved. If we look at some of the top questions in the last month ([1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/166313/sorting-large-1gb-file-with-100-millions-numbers-using-merge-sort), [2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/167301/send-a-tweet-to-isp-when-internet-speed-drops), [3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/167422/sorting-algorithms-bubble-sort), [4](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/169452/simple-generic-cache), [5](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/169530/validating-credit-card-numbers-using-python)), we notice that the highest-voted answers tend to be long and include a lot of discussion, and every question has multiple upvoted answers.

And although I agree with Laure that ultimately there is less freedom to achieve a stated goal in programming than there is translation, I suspect that the parameters of translation review could also be clearly defined and that such a definition would mitigate the dangers. That is, we would work within a policy. In fact, I think one reason Code Review doesn't implode is that there is a clear definition not only of answer policy but also of good questions: a person can't ask "Write this program for me" but "Here's what I'm trying to do, here's what I've tried, and here's what I want feedback on" (which may well be an XY problem in some cases). Our corresponding ideal question might be: "*A* is the text and its source, *B* is my analysis of its genre & meaning, *C* is my target audience, and this is how I've tried to express *B* to *C*. Have I preserved these dimensions / achieved what I set out to do?"<sup>1</sup> Another type of question is analytic: "Here's a translation I found in the wild, here are the details, etc. Here are my thoughts on it. I don't know why they made this choice; why is it the right one?" Such questions answered well can yield valuable insights about usage and interpretation.

Insofar as that would be our model, it would overlap with what Laure has pointed out is something we already do, as in that question she cited: with enough detail provided and evidence of thought on the asker's part, we sometimes analyze French text and suggest improvements. The difference is that we would more clearly delineate that activity from other types of questions. This would not be a tag for asking a grammar question, for example, if feedback on the translation is sought. It would also not be a "How do you say?" service any more than Code Review is a "How do you program?" service. Instead, we would have a category with defined criteria that allow us to easily rule on the many questions we already get of this kind — i.e., we could say that the question "Is Google Translate right about this?" is a bad *translation* question, which I consider an advantage over only saying that it's a bad *question* (not that it can't be both). In other words, this "gate" and its gatekeeper criteria could serve as a better framework to handle the input that already comes to us. Indeed, translation-esque questions [tend](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1793/french-equivalent-of-the-expression-last-but-not-least-un-%C3%A9quivalent-%C3%A0-lexp/) to [be](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/26169/french-for-blood-will-tell/26173#26173) more [popular](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/26229/in-french-how-do-you-say-living-under-a-rock) than [most](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2975/comment-traduire-what-the-fuck/3009#3009) when not closed. (That doesn't constitute an endorsement; in fact, the multiplicity of answers may be a sign of just what we're trying to avoid: emotional, opinion-based topics. Indeed, we may find that many questions that we would be able to more clearly evaluate would deserve closure. But it is any case an observation about traffic that we could perhaps stand to have a more developed policy for handling.)

One objection might be that questions thus delineated would be better suited to the proposed translation SE. My response is that in my admittedly brief time on the network, I've often been surprised by the number and fineness of the distinctions made between sites. Computer science, as the flagship topic of the network, fills its space extremely densely, taking up the majority of the first three columns in the footer plus the 26 "more". I consider that French language and the world its speakers inhabit are no less vast a subject, and translation into French is not the same thing as translation theory; consider that translation degrees have you focus on courses on translation between a particular language pair. An ideally saturated language section of the SE network could well have French language learning, French language and usage, translation into French, French culture, and more as individual sites. But as our size is not great enough to support all those diverse communities yet, it seems reasonable to subsume French translation as we have French language learning — even if we have resisted subsuming French culture (except as it interfaces with linguistic questions).

Those are my thoughts, anyhow. From here I'll just analyze a couple of questions along the lines of a hypothetical framework.

1. [How do you say "The sink drains slowly"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/26503/how-do-you-say-the-sink-drains-slowly)

> To close and/or retag. This is a nearly context-free "How do you say this?" question. That is, it's a translation request and not translation review.

2. [Translation of “arm bike”](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/22090/translation-of-arm-bike)

> This asker at least provides their take on it, and a picture which can serve as the "source text". It can be answered but probably will not be upvoted.

3. [Correct interpretation of "on y porte les valeurs" in a mathematical context](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/21485/correct-translation-of-porte)

> Our framework would allow us to close this on the grounds that it is a translation out of French. (If properly re-asked, it could be turned into an interpretation question.) As it stands it was dealt with inconsistently.

4. [Why "langage de programmation" and not "langue de programmation"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/386/why-langage-de-programmation-and-not-langue-de-programmation)

> A fairly well-formulated question that we could fit under the subheading: "When does French handle this idea (that is served by one word in language X) one way, and when does it handle it another way?" The complementary subheading is, "How can French express both of these things (that are distinguished in language X but not in French)?" In this case, perhaps more fortunate than most, the answer went in the direction one would hope and ended up being well-sourced, definite, and informative about French usage.

5. [Comment traduire « what the fuck » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2975/comment-traduire-what-the-fuck/3009#3009)

> This question gives a lot of background and proposes the very interesting option, "Shall we translate this *at all*?"

6. [What languages are perceived as classy or fancy to French speakers?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24724/what-languages-are-perceived-as-classy-or-fancy-to-french-speakers)

> This had close votes before; I presume they expired. But this question could have been formulated a little differently to yield something that fits our hypothetical framework: "How can we handle this phenomenon when transposing text into French?" (This is how I answered it as a new user of the site at the time.)

I'll just rest on this last one to say that I believe there are many more phenomena of this kind. To take one example, I just reread the David Bellos book cited in my answer there, and he discussed an interesting case: when Freud was first translated from German to English, his coinages like *Schaulust* were rendered more like *scopophilia*. The source is composed of everyday German words, but the target is so far from the everyday that it's not even English — it's Greek. Why? Because the scientific communities of the two languages have very different traditions of terminology.

It seems to me that a domain like "French scientific terminology", or any other domain in which the French language is used, lived, and developed, can be legitimately approached not only through the usage questions we currently allow, but also on the basis of how a given sentence from translation fits into it.

<sub><sup>1</sup>Having to present an analysis of the source and the asker's own French attempt also helps mitigate the glaring theoretical problem with translations: a good review requires knowledge of the source language, and we do not by any means want to predicate this forum on expertise in English — any more than it already has been! I might note as well that not every question will meet with someone capable of answering it, regardless of the topic.</sub>

---

La réponse de Laure me semble très sensée, mais afin d'examiner de façon plus détaillée les deux côtés j'exprimerai quelques idées qui tendent à l'autre conclusion.

Pour moi, la comparaison avec Code Review est pertinente. Quand je considère la programmation que j'ai faite, je trouve que la moité est des maths et l'autre est du langage ; moi je l'aborde à travers ce deuxième aspect. Le travail soulève des questions qui correspondent à la sémantique (quel terme convient le mieux ici), à la syntaxe (comment faut-il arranger ces termes), et au style (comment le rendrai-je plus concis mais clair). Le jugement y est impliqué. Lorsqu'on lit certaines des questions posées le mois passé ([1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/166313/sorting-large-1gb-file-with-100-millions-numbers-using-merge-sort), [2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/167301/send-a-tweet-to-isp-when-internet-speed-drops), [3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/167422/sorting-algorithms-bubble-sort), [4](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/169452/simple-generic-cache), [5](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/169530/validating-credit-card-numbers-using-python)), on constate que les réponses les plus upvotées ont tendance à être longues et comprennent beaucoup de discussion, et que toute question a plusieurs réponses upvotées.

Enfin, bien que je suis d'accord avec Laure qu'au bout du compte la programmation est moins flexible que la traduction quant aux moyens d'accomplir un but désigné, je suppose que les paramètres d'analyse de traduction pourraient également être définis de façon non-ambiguë et qu'une telle définition atténuerait les dangers. C'est-à-dire qu'on travaillerait avec une politique. Je dirais en effet que Code Review existe grâce en partie à ce qu'il y a une définition claire non seulement de la politique des réponses mais aussi des questions acceptables : on ne peut pas demander « Écrivez ce programme pour moi » mais plutôt « Voici ce que je vise à faire, voici mon essai, et voici ce que j'aimerais qu'on commente » (ce qui pourrait bien être un problème XY selon le cas). Notre question idéale parallèle serait peut-être : « Voici un texte *A* avec sa source ; *B* est mon analyse de son genre et de sa signification ; *C* sont les lecteurs idéaux que j'ai en tête ; et voici comment j'ai essayé de dire *B* à *C*. Ai-je bien préservé ces dimensions / accomplit ce que je visais ? »<sup>1</sup> Un autre type de question serait analytique : « Voici une traduction que j'ai trouvé quelque part, en voici les détails, etc. Voici ce que j'en pense. Je n'arrive pas à comprendre pourquoi on a choisi cette formulation ; pourquoi conviendrait-il ? » De telles questions bien résolues peuvent produire des aperçus valables sur l'usage et l'art d'interpréter.

Si tel était notre modèle, il y aurait un chevauchement entre ceci et ce qu'on fait déjà, comme a dit Laure en citant une question de ce type : si l'on donne assez de détails et que le soin apporté à la question est manifeste, nous analysons parfois un texte en français et suggérons des améliorations. La différence serait que nous délinéerions de façon plus claire cette activité des autres types de questions. Il ne s'agirait pas par exemple d'une étiquette à laquelle conviendraient des questions de grammaire si on souhaite l'analyse d'une traduction. Ce ne serait pas non plus un service pour répondre aux questions « Comment dit-on ? » tout comme Code Review n'est pas un service pour les questions « Comment programme-t-on ? » Nous aurions plutôt une catégorie avec des critères bien définis qui nous permettraient de prononcer des jugements sur les questions que nous recevons actuellement en grand nombre — c'est-à-dire que nous pourrions dire que la question « Google Translate a-t-il raison de dire que ... ? » est une mauvaise question de *traduction*, et je pense que cela est mieux que de pouvoir seulement dire que c'est une mauvaise *question* (bien sûr que les deux seraient vrais). En d'autres termes, cette « porte » et ses gardiens de critères pourraient servir de cadre pour gérer le trafic qui nous vient déjà. Les questions de traduction [sont](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1793/french-equivalent-of-the-expression-last-but-not-least-un-%C3%A9quivalent-%C3%A0-lexp/) en [effet](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/26169/french-for-blood-will-tell/26173#26173) parmi [les](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/26229/in-french-how-do-you-say-living-under-a-rock) plus [populaires](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2975/comment-traduire-what-the-fuck/3009#3009) lorsqu'elles ne sont pas fermées. (Ceci n'en représente pas mon approbation ; peut-être que la multiplicité de réponses est en effet un indicateur de la question même qu'on cherche à éviter : des sujets basés sur l'émotion et l'opinion. On pourrait bien se rendre compte que beaucoup des questions qu'on est en mesure d'évaluer plus clairement mériteraient la clôture. Mais ceci est quand même une constatation que nous bénéficerions peut-être d'une politique de gestion de ce trafic.)

Une objection possible : les questions ainsi délinéées conviendraient mieux à un site SE comme celui proposé pour la traduction. Ma réponse : Pendant mon temps sur ce réseau (qui j'avoue pour l'instant a été bref), j'ai été surpris plusieurs fois de découvrir que les distinctions qu'on fait entre les sites sont nombreuses et minitieuses. L'informatique, sujet phare du réseau, remplit de façon très dense son espace : elle représente la majorité des sites dans les premières trois colonnes au bas de page ainsi que les 26 « en plus ». Je considère que la langue française et le monde qu'habite ses locuteurs ne sont pas moins vastes comme sujets, et que la traduction vers le français n'est pas la même chose que la traduction théorique ; nous noterons que les diplômes en traduction exigent qu'on se concentre dans des cours de traduction entre deux langues particulières. Une collection idéalement saturée du réseau SE pourrait bien comprendre l'apprentissage du français, l'usage du français, la traduction vers le français, la culture française, et plus, en tant que sites distincts. Mais comme la communauté n'est pas encore assez grande pour soutenir toutes ces diverses communautés possibles, on pourrait dire qu'intégrer la traduction vers le français serait raisonnable — tout comme on a intégré l'apprentissage du français, même si on a résisté à l'intégration de la culture française (sauf lorsqu'elle est liée à des questions linguistiques).

Voilà ma pensée en tout cas. Ensuite j'analyserai quelques questions selon un cadre hypothétique.

1. [How do you say "The sink drains slowly"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/26503/how-do-you-say-the-sink-drains-slowly)

> À fermer où à changer d'étiquette. Ceci est une question presque sans contexte du type « Comment dit-on ? » C'est-à-dire qu'il s'agit d'une requête d'une traduction et non d'une revue d'une traduction.

2. [Translation of “arm bike”](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/22090/translation-of-arm-bike)

> Cette personne donne au moins leur essai, et une image qui peut servir de « texte source ». Il est possible d'y répondre mais il est peu probable que la question serait upvotée.

3. [Correct interpretation of "on y porte les valeurs" in a mathematical context](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/21485/correct-translation-of-porte)

> Notre système nous permettrait de fermer cette question parce qu'il s'agit d'une traduction du français en une autre langue. (Une fois reformulée, elle serait peut-être une question d'interprétation.) Pour l'instant on l'a gérée de façon inconstante.

4. [Why "langage de programmation" and not "langue de programmation"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/386/why-langage-de-programmation-and-not-langue-de-programmation)

> Une question assez bien formulée que nous considérerions comme appartenant à la sous-catégorie : « Quand le français exprime-t-il ce concepte (pour lequel langue X se sert d'un seul mot) ainsi, et quand l'exprime-t-il ainsi par contre ? » La sous-catégorie complémentaire est « Comment le français peut-il exprimer ces deux conceptes (qui sont distincts en langue X mais pas en français) ? » Quant à cette question, qui a peut-être réussi mieux que ne font la plupart, la réponse est du genre souhaité : bien justifiée, définitive, et informatrice sur l'usage.

5. [Comment traduire « what the fuck » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2975/comment-traduire-what-the-fuck/3009#3009)

> Cette question inclut beaucoup de contexte et propose le choix très intéressant : « Peut-être qu'il ne faut pas du tout traduire cette expression ? »

6. [What languages are perceived as classy or fancy to French speakers?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24724/what-languages-are-perceived-as-classy-or-fancy-to-french-speakers)

> On avait voté pour fermer cette question ; je présume que les votes ont expiré. Mais elle aurait pu être formulée un peu différement pour en tirer une question qui convient à notre cadre hypothétique : « Comment devrons-nous nous charger de ce phénomène lors de sa transposition en français ? » (C'est à cette formulation que j'y ai répondu en tant que nouveau membre de ce site en ce temps-là.)

Pour terminer en examinant ce dernier, je crois qu'il existe beaucoup plus de phénomènes comme celui-là. Pour en donner un exemple, je viens de relire le livre de David Bellos cité dans ma réponse dans ce fil-là, et celui-ci a parlé d'un cas intéressant : lorsque l'œuvre de Freud a été traduite pour la première fois de l'allemand vers l'anglais, ses néologismes comme *Schaulust* ont été traduits par des termes comme *scopophilia*. Le terme d'origine est constitué de mots allemands très courants, mais le terme cible se trouve être si loin du langage de tous les jours que ce n'est même pas de l'anglais — c'est du grec. Pourquoi ? Parce que les communautés scientifiques des deux langues possèdent des traditions terminologiques très distinctes.

Il me semble qu'un domaine tel que « la terminologie scientifique du français », ou n'importe quel autre domaine où est parlée, vécue, ou développée la langue française, peut être abordé non seulement à travers les questions d'usage que nous permettons actuellement, mais aussi en examinant comment s'y incorpore telle ou telle phrase à traduire.

<sub><sup>1</sup>Devoir présenter une analyse de la source et son propre essai aide aussi à attenuer le problème théorique flagrant des traductions : une bonne analyse exige la connaissance de la langue d'origine, et on ne veut point baser ce forum sur les compétences en anglais — du moins pas plus qu'il ne l'est déjà ! Je pourrais noter aussi que ce n'est pas pour toutes les questions qu'on trouvera quelqu'un qui puisse y répondre quel que soit le domaine.</sub>

Comment: Great answer :) I had just allowed a variation on the gate of the form 'I wish to express this to someone, here' s what I wrote,  is it idiomaticand correctly written? ' (for the case of a feed back mail for exemple, where there' s no source text)

Comment: @Tensibai Ah, but I think a question like that isn't quite the category I envision: the basic question sounds like "How do you say this?" and not "Have I created a good translation?" The latter might take an answer to the former as its starting point. Although the distinction in practice might end up too fine to rely on...

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Many thanks for the corrections. Now, can you clarify "relecture" ? From my understanding, that means what you just did to this text (proofread), but I take the activity in question to be more than that: review, analysis, discussion... Can "relecture" be used more broadly than I thought?

Comment: Well code review is just this 'I aim to express X, here's what I did, is it OK or is there improvements ?'. The question about clogged sink is very symptomatic of what I mean, as is it show a lack of research an effort, according to the problem exhibited there, it the author has been allowed to tell 'I wrote a feedback to my airbnb host, here's what I plan to send, does it sounds clear enough and correct ?' would be fitting the main idea (I think).

Comment: Late thinking coming to my mind: this proposition is more or less what Stéphane did to the French part of this post with the addition of explanation of why he did choose one word over the other. ("Revue" carries a sense of reviewing factual things like "Revue des comptes" or "Revue des résultats" where "relecture" carries the sense of reading again searching for errors which would be translated to "proof reading" I think)

Comment: @Tensibai I do think that's like the *relecture* that Stéphane introduced, and I do keep the two notions separate. You have a point that in Code Review they come without "source texts", but I still don't consider what's done on CR to be the same as the sink question. On StackOverflow one asks "How can I do X?" and usually there are only one or two possible paths to take and they aren't very contentious. But on CR you ask "How well did I do this?" and get a detailed analysis of your method and the implications of your choices. The latter is what I envision for this kind of translation review.

Comment: (Not that the sink question, properly researched and asked, couldn't be okay on this site. But I would still classify it as "How do I say this?" rather than as translation review. Again, in practice, looking at real questions it may be harder to make such theoretical distinctions, but for me it's the ideal.)

Comment: Agree on the whole comment :)

Comment: Ok *analyse* fits better than *relecture* if proofreading is not what you meant. *Revue* carries the meaning of systematic checking while going over a given list of things. It didn't sound right here.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Thanks; that makes sense.